# Can't save changes to child tables using LINQ to SQL that have foreign key constraints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to teach myself LINQ to SQL and have decided to do a small MVC.NET project to get my feet wet. The problem is that I have fallen very early on with the following error.

I am making a golf application so I have setup the database and got my dbml classes made. The database has a `course` table and a `hole` table. The `hole` table references the `courseId` by its primary key and has a foreigh key constraint on it. So all pretty standard.

I have an MVC action on my controller that allows me to edit the course information (name, and hole info, for example, par and stroke index, etc.)

When I do the save after an edit I get the following error.

"***An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a Course and a Hole. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (Hole.CourseId) cannot be set to null***."

I have debugged this and can't see any problems. Is there something I need to do on the database to allow me to edit tables with foreign key constraints?

Here is the action code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var courseViewModel = new CourseViewModel { Course = _repository.GetCourse(id) };

        if (courseViewModel.Course == null)
        {
            return View("NotFound", string.Format("Course {0} Not Found", id));
        }

        try
        {
            UpdateModel(courseViewModel);
            _repository.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddRuleViolations(courseViewModel.Course.GetRuleViolations());
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);

            return View(courseViewModel);
        }
    }
```

Where _repository looks like this:

```
    namespace Web.Repository
    {
        public class MyRepository
        {
            private MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

            public void SubmitChanges()
            {
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }

            public Course GetCourse(int id)
            {
                return db.Courses.SingleOrDefault(i => i.CourseId == id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does UpdateModel do? Assuming it makes changes to the Course member on your view model, you might want to consider a repository method like this:

```
public void SaveCourse(Course course)
{
  db.Courses.Attach(course);
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. UpdateModel is a call to the standard MVC Controller.UpdateModel() method. In this case it updates courseViewModel with changes made on the client, so changes to courseViewModel.Course and courseViewModel.Course.Holes as well

Comment: I have tried this suggestion but now get :
    "Cannot attach an entity that already exists."

Comment: It seems then that the context is never lost but the UpdateModel is setting your FK field to null. It may be preferable to separate your view model from your entity, post to your view model and do an explicit update to your retrieved entity with only those values you wish to modify.